# 2 Layouts in Polymer (ie: Main-App, Signup)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In the PSK, the index.html references a my-app.html template. In there I have my main layout with app-drawer, header ect..

How do I then have a page without that template which just has for example a centered card with login fields.

Do I somehow use my-app.html to just contain nested layouts for each?

```
index.html
-my-app.html
--main-shell.html (main content with iron-pages)
--blank.html (for signup/login)
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you don't add the ```<main-shell>``` element to the body just only the blank then you can create it on the fly when the authentication successed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to those that ask, that below the `my-app` element you create a `my-session` element which handles authentication and a `my-pages` element to manage the application itself.  Within `my-session` I unhide a login element if that is needed (I allow users with an authenticated cookie to access the application without logging in).

My `my-app`'s outline is like this

```
<app-header-layout>
  <app-header
    fixed
    effects="waterfall">
    <app-toolbar>
       ...
     </app-toolbar>
  </app-header>
  <my-session id="session" user="{{user}}"></my-session>
  <my-pages
    id="pages"
    user="[[user]]"
    unresolved
    hidden="[[!isLoggedOn]]" >APPLICATION LOADING</my-pages>
</app-header-layout>
```

`my-session` then has a `my-login` element which will contain the login form centered on a `paper-card` in the middle of the page

This is done with

```
<dom-module id="my-session">
  <template>
  <style>
    [hidden] {
      display: none!important;
    }
  </style>
    <iron-ajax
      id="validateuser"
      url="/api/validate_user"
      handle-as="json"
      method="POST"
      body="{}"
      content-type="application/json"
      on-response="_validated"></iron-ajax>
    <iron-ajax
      id="logoff"
      url="/logoff"
      body="{}"
      handle-as="json"
      method = "POST"
      content-type="application/json"></iron-ajax>
    <my-waiting waiting="[[waiting]]"></my-waiting>
    <my-logon user="{{user}}" hidden="[[!needsLogon]]"></my-logon>
  </template>
  <script>...</script>
</dom-module>
```

The iron-ajax requests are to validate a users cookie (I still ask the server to validate it, since it contains an encrypted token) and to log of the user.  This is all handled in javascript which I don't show (for simplicities sake).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!